# iOS Remote Notifications Badge Count Strategy When Network Connection Is Poor

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to understand the best practice for remote notifications on iOS when the user has a particularly poor network connection or no network connection.

The scenario is such:

The user gets some remote notifications and at some point in the future opens the app. At this point I wan't to let the server know ASAP that the badge count is now zero. I am using server side badge count management as the only way you can update the icon badge reliably is in the APNS payload. However the call to the server fails as there is no network connectivity. Then the user puts the app into the background so I can't make any further calls to the server if network came back. Subsequently a new remote notification comes in but the badge number is wrong because the server doesn't know it needed to be zeroed.

Am I missing something here? Any advice gratefully received as I haven't found any articles online dealing with this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have implemented in right way. We can't do anything if there is problem in internet connection. Badge count is managed by server only. So, whenever you open application, application will update Zero to server. Now, if it is not properly updated to server then it is not possible to manage it from Mobile side.